# Convert millisecond to seconds like (0.24)

Tags: c#

I have one integer value which is 48. when i am using divide for this number from 100 using calculator then the value is 0.48. but the same i am trying with my code then getting 0 value.

like int value=48.
int changeValue = 48/100;

changeValue value is:0.

Need help.

Answer (score 2):

int is for integer values. use float or double:

```
double changeValue = 48.0 / 100;
```

When you are trying to divide one integer number on another you get also integer value and the value is rounded to lower (24 / 5 = 4)
If you want to get not integer value you should make sure that one of your numbers is also not integer. Thats why I wrote 48.0 intead of 48.

If you alread have integer value in an integer variable, like

```
int msec = 48;
```

you should first make it floating:

```
int msec = 48;
double sec = (double)msec / 100;
```